# where does Django Storage save the file infomation(like name,path,url etc.)

Tags: django, file, file-upload, filesystems, storage

I recently was learning the diango upload mechanism ,but i got a one thing confusing ,It's about the storage of the uploaded file infomation, i know if i creat model with FileField in it,and i use the modelform ,config the DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE as default which is django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage .i set the FileField's Upload_to='Video'.

my confusion is :
 where would the file infomation(like name,path,url,etc that FileSystemStorages would provide,not the file itself) save to, It seem that django create a foreignKey Table(Model) that store these file infomation ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FileField` only cares about the local filename and storage mechanism; other fields in the table must be used to give the file a meaningful external name.